# Statistical methods not mentioned in standard literature (e.g. Wooldridge)?

Tags: references, econometrics

In my PhD course I have often heard of statistical methods called
**principal component analysis (PCA),
linear discriminant analysis (LDA),
propensity score matching (PSM),
latent cluster analysis (LCA)**
etc.

However, none of these methods are mentioned in standard *(edit: econometrics)* literature like **Wooldridge or Greene**.

How come? 
Is it because mentioned books focus on random samples and the techniques mentioned above refer to samples generated by experiments?

Edit: I just started my PhD in the field of entrepreneurship/innovation after a masters in finance and am now looking into applied e-commerce and consumer behavior/choice research.

Comment: Please add more detail to your post about your field of study by editing your post.  As you mentioned Greene and Wooldridge, I assume that you are an economics student.  As a general rule, when you are referencing the literature, you should add the full citation to the book or article in question, as the users of this site come from diverse backgrounds, and may not necessarily be familiar with the authors you mention.  In addition, people like Wooldridge and Greene have several textbooks out, so it is good to know specifically which one you are referring to

Comment: A quick google research shows that Jeffrey M. Wooldridge is the author of a number of introductory books on econometrics. I am not sure this qualifies as standard literature *in general*. Maybe, the methods you listed are not widely used in this area (econometrics), so they are omitted in introductory texts.

Comment: @T.E.G., PSM is becoming more popular in econometrics, at least for those of us who do impact evaluation work (incidentally, the two World Bank impact evaluation books [Impact Evaluation in Practice by Gertler et al. and Handbook of Impact Evaluation by Khandker et al.] both go into PSM).  In my experience, PCA is more commonly used by biostatisticians than economists; I also have psychologist colleagues who use PCA quite a bit.

Comment: The confusion may lie in your notion of the *standard literature*. Implicit in your query is an assumption that books by Wooldridge and Greene, which are focused in economics and econometrics, are *standard*. Obviously, this is not the case. The methods you point to have been written about extensively in other, non-economic disciplines including statistics, statistical learning, machine learning, and so on.

Comment: The big Wooldridge book has a section on PSM... As for the other methods you listed, that are not really used in Economics at least I cant think of paper (applied or semi applied) that uses PCA/LDA/LCA. This does mean that these methods are bad, or unless, but just that they dont help economists to answser their questions.

Comment: Statistics is a broad field of study.  There is a great deal of overlap between econometrics and statistics particularly in the area of time series. In fact there are a number of mathematicians and statisticians who were able to become Nobel Prize winners thanks to the field of economics.  John Nash being one publicized in the book and movie "A Beautiful Mind."   There is no reason to think that you will find your favorite topic in an advanced statistics book or a particular statistical journal.  Specialization is common in many fields and growing.

Comment: The question would make more sense if you referred to *standard econometrics textbooks* (because Wooldridge and Greene are clearly standard/classical texts in econometrics) rather than *standard statistical literature*.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. You are probably right in a sense in my graduate studies (finance) at university I was given a quite narrow econometric view on research. E.g. no view into experimental data analysis

Comment: In short, economists love their regressions. However, if you look at sub-fields of economics, you do see methods outside of or perhaps only mentioned in Greene and Woolrdridge. In labor, PSM has a fairly strong set of practitioners. A leading discussion paper is Dehejia and Wahba as well as Heckmann and his students. There is a 2015 book by Imbens and Rubin *Causal Inference* focusing on a broader set of tools that include PSM. Imbens is a leading econometrician who taught NBER courses with Wooldridge. In behavioral econ, experiments and related methods are popular.

Comment: "economists love their regressions" - what about structural equation models (SEM)?

Comment: I see them a lot in other social sciences like psychology, often mentioning that they are ideal to deal with more complex dependencies. But I am sure there are complex dependencies in economic research as well? Why are the economists rarely using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view of what is a "standard" text seems to be restricted to what may be seen in econometrics.

Statistics is much, much broader than the subset of it that is the focus of econometricians.

This is to be expected, since the kinds of questions econometricians want to answer, and the kinds of data they can get, are different from what is common in other areas (econometricians don't tend to focus on classification problems for example). Those things will tend to shape the methods that are used and the kinds of problems in applying that methodology that need to be solved.

So, for example, econometrics deals with multivariate data, but it tends to deal with it over time rather than cross-sectionally (and so less likely to use PCA, for example). It also tends to be observational rather than experimental, so even though (for example) a researcher in psychology and one in econometrics may both deal with longitudinal data, the psych researcher will tend to deal with quite short series in a controlled experiment, while the econometrics research will tend to deal with longer series in an observational setting (and typically with quite different assumptions about the structure of the variables and their relationships).

The same goes with methods common in machine learning, for example -- the questions they ask tend to be different, and the kinds of data that are available tend to be different, too. So there's much more of a focus on approaches like classification and clustering, and a lot of the problems relate to very large data  sets, which impacts the kinds of techniques that are used (for example, even though OLS regression has a closed-form solution, that closed-form solution is often not the best idea when dealing with some really big data sets).

That is not to say that a good fraction of the techniques in use in areas outside econometrics would have no econometric applications, though; each application area -- econometrics included -- has a tendency to focus on a subset of the tools that would be useful for the kinds of data that they deal with. Technological inertia -- doing what we do because that's what everyone we know does (which in turn impacts what is taught to the next generation) -- is a very real issue (though only to be expected) and affects every area of application of statistics. There's also a bit of a tendency to reinvent the wheel (when sometimes better versions the wheel are already in use elsewhere).

It can be very fruitful to explore what other people do, even if you don't see immediate applications for it. Picking up a stats book or two with applications in a variety of areas can be both interesting and informative (and, occasionally, baffling, especially at first).